# How do I do a try/catch for my specific API Call example?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, try-catch

so my question is very specific. Whenever I run this bit from my page I get an error if I don't input the CORRECT ID I need to search for in the API. It doesn't know what to do when it doesn't make a valid API call because the query string is incorrect. How do I go about redirecting to a different page WHEN there's an error like that or how do I prevent it from STOPPING the program? I'm assuming there's a try catch in here but I tried it multiple different ways and I'm still confused because it doesn't work. Help please! I'm new to this... Here's the snippet. The request portion of the code is where the error occurs if the "bnetID" is not a valid ID. If it is valid it runs perfectly fine...

```
// Make a GET request to the /results page (When submit is pressed)
app.get("/results", function(req, res){

    // Retrieve bnetID and REGION from the FORM
    var bnetID = req.query.bnetID;
    var region = req.query.region;

    // Replace the # with a -
    bnetID = bnetID.replace("#", "-");

    // Create the query string
    var url = "http://ow-api.herokuapp.com/profile/pc/"+ region +"/"+bnetID;

    // Make the API request
    request(url, function(err, response, body){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            var playerData = JSON.parse(body);
            playerData = findImportantData(bnetID, playerData);
            checkIfExists(bnetID, playerData);
            res.render("results", {data: playerData});
        }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you handle what you want to do if there is an error?

```
    if(err){
        console.log(err); // change this to whatever you want to do
    }
```

Comment: what do you mean? sry I'm not good at this stuff I'm learning... whenever that reaches to that error the program just cancels, i don't want it to do that.. whenever it doesn't work it just says rqeuest could not be proxied on mybrowser

Comment: Right - and so what's happening is that when there is an error `(err)` -> you `console.log()` it and that's it. You can put anything you want inside of that block, so you can reroute to a different page if you'd like.

Comment: what about `if(err) { window.location.href = "https://www.google.com" }` ? doesn't matter really, do anything you want.

Comment: You can use https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.redirect to redirect to a different route.

Comment: i'm trying that but it says res.render / res.redirect is not a function in the if(err) scope :< what's going onnn

Comment: because you're passing `response` not `res` - try `response.redirect` or `response.render` or change your parameter names.